# In Scala how to not reference the Array element to the variable

Tags: scala, scala-collections, arraybuffer

I don't want to reference anything in this piece of code.

```
var nums : ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(10, 12, 13, 14, 15)
var num : Int = nums(0)

num += 6

println(num)
println(nums)
```

When I print nums it prints 16, 12, 13, 14, 15 because of referencing the first element of the array. Is there a way to just give the first element value of the nums array to a variable without referencing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it prints:

> ArrayBuffer(10, 12, 13, 14, 15)

It's because, as [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int.html) states:

> Int, a 32-bit signed integer (equivalent to Java's int primitive type) is a subtype of scala.AnyVal. Instances of Int are not represented by an object in the underlying runtime system.

Comment: So it doesn't reference the array?

Comment: Did you run it? What did you get?

Comment: The problem wasn't about referencing it was about my code. Thank you.

Comment: @MehmetBerkCetin, you should then remove your question, instead of leaving it "on hold".